# How to do expontential slider price range jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I found this slider code here:

http://codepen.io/ignaty/pen/EruAe

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var w1 = 40;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var w2 = 40;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;

    }

// // slider call

$('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function(event, ui) {

        $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html('$' + ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max').html('$' + ui.values[ 1 ]);
        $('.price-range-both').html('<i>$' + ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - </i>$' + ui.values[ 1 ] );

        //

    if ( ui.values[0] == ui.values[1] ) {
      $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'inline');
    }

        //

        if (collision($('.price-range-min'), $('.price-range-max')) == true) {
            $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '0');    
            $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'block');     
        } else {
            $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '1');    
            $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'none');      
        }

    }
});

$('.ui-slider-range').append('<span class="price-range-both value"><i>$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0 ) + ' - </i>' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1 ) + '</span>');

$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').append('<span class="price-range-min value">$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0 ) + '</span>');

$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1)').append('<span class="price-range-max value">$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1 ) + '</span>');
```

I would like to have an option to change the exponents like skip by 100 or any other exponents.

What code should I add to make it work that way? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Have you seen `step` option http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps in slider plugin API ?

Comment: Oh yeah! I didn't see that! Got it! Thank you! :) Please do make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the `step` option [jqueryui.com/slider/#steps](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps) in slider plugin API. 
The plugin documentation says:

```
step option determines the size or amount of each interval or step the slider takes between the min and max. The full specified value range of the slider (max - min) should be evenly divisible by the step.

Code examples:
$( ".selector" ).slider({ step: 5 });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Note: There's an issue with my code! And I can't figure out a fix.

**The values aren't actually being squared, just the printed numbers. If I could figure out a way to make it look right on load I'd say just run the values through your exponential function before you save and call it good. Not really a good solution, sorry!**

Here's an updated fiddle with the changes that <strike>should get you what you desire</strike> will get you about half way there but only on the surface: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgCyo

What I did:

1. In the `.slide` handler, I squared each value. This is where you will put whatever exponential function you need, where the unknowns are `ui.values[0]` and `ui.values[1]` respectively.

   ```
   // lines 23-24
   ui.values[0] = ui.values[0] * ui.values[0];
   ui.values[1] = ui.values[1] * ui.values[1];
   ```
2. Now that the numbers are so large, I needed to increase their hitboxes so they wouldn't overlap. To do this, I just doubled the "fudge" value in the `collision` function. You'll have to find a value that suits your application.

   ```
     var w1 = 80; // Line 3
   ```

   and

   ```
     var w2 = 80; // Line 6
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://codepen.io/mailmindlin/pen/mrdJn) pen.

The slider is technically still linear, but it displays prices exponentially.

This function takes the current value, and changes it to fit a parabola.

```
function calcValue(value) {
  var a=.005;
  var b=1;
  var c=0;
  return (a*value*value + b*value + c).toFixed(0);
};
```